How can I show a splash on the Elevated button when I press it?
How can I show a splash or some indication when the button is pressed for an Elevated button.
Here is the code snippet:
ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    overlayColor: WidgetStateProperty.all(
        const Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 99, 167)),
    splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
    backgroundColor: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    context.read<StripeCheckoutCubit>().initiateCheckout(
        userRef: userData.selfRef,
        planRef: pricePlans.first.selfRef);
  },
  child: Text(
    'Checkout',
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 17,
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
  ),
),

I used the splashFactory but it is not doing anything.

Do You want to change the color when you pressing the button?

Yes, I want to change the color

Try below code In this code when you pressed the button then color has been changed.
Refer MaterialStateProperty, ButtonStyle, material-state, WidgetState
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        context.read<StripeCheckoutCubit>().initiateCheckout(
          userRef: userData.selfRef,
          planRef: pricePlans.first.selfRef,
        );
      },
      style: ButtonStyle(
        overlayColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith(
          (states) {
            return states.contains(WidgetState.pressed)
                ? Colors.green
                : null;
          },
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(
        'Checkout',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 17, color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
      ),
    ),


Yes, that works, I slightly modified the code.
